# Java Searching LinkedList for data return true/false?

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list

I need write a method to loop through a linked list searching to see if Object data is in linked list. Any help?

```
public class LinkedList {
     private LinkedListNode head;
     public boolean find(Object data){
          for(somethinggoeshere..){
               if(head==data){
                    return true;
          }else{
          return false;
     }
}
```

Any help?

Edit: My LinkedListNode class:

```
public class LinkedListNode {

private Object data;
private LinkedListNode next;


public LinkedListNode(Object data, LinkedListNode next) {
    super();
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}

public Object getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public LinkedListNode getNext() {
    return next;
}
public void setNext(LinkedListNode next) {
    this.next = next;
}
}
```

Edit: Final solution for those who are interested:

```
public class LinkedList {

private LinkedListNode head;

public boolean find(Object data){
      LinkedListNode temp = head;
      while(temp!= null)  // check if you have reached the tail
      {
           if(data.equals(temp.getData()))
           {
                return true;
           }
           temp = temp.getNext(); // move to the next node
      } // end of while loop
      return false;
 } // end of find method
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend calling your class `LinkedList`.. you may confuse it for Java's `LinkedList` class

Comment: What have you tried? Did you create the LinkedListNode Object? Why cant you just see if LinkedListNode.NextNode == null?

Comment: The linkedlist I will be traversing will have data in it. The whole reason I am doing this is to search through a linkedlist with a set of characters such as "ump" and return if the phrase "ump" occurs in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you wrote the code for `LinkedListNode`, you should know wether or not is `Iterable`, and thus be able to loop through it with a for-each loop like that.

As it stands, you should traverse the nodes either recursively or in an iterative manner, by using some form of "next" pointers that is held within each node, and in essence do a linear search through the links until you find the data you are looking for, or return `null`.

Here's a link for some help on implementing a linked list:

http://www.danielacton.com/Data-Structures/Linked-List/Java/

Comment: I do have a LinkedList Node class setup:

    public class LinkedListNode {

 private Object data;
 private LinkedListNode next;
 
 
 public LinkedListNode(Object data, LinkedListNode next) {
  super();
  this.data = data;
  this.next = next;
 }
 
 public Object getData() {
  return data;
 }
 public void setData(Object data) {
  this.data = data;
 }
 public LinkedListNode getNext() {
  return next;
 }
 public void setNext(LinkedListNode next) {
  this.next = next;
 }
 
Which way do you recommend doing it? Recursively or iteratively?
I'm having trouble displaying that as code, sorry.

Comment: Could you post that code as part of the question to see it better?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your LinkedList and search for the data. If you reach tail of the list and still unable to find the data this implies that data is not in the LinkedList.

I am assuming that LinkedListNode  has a member variable data to store the data in each node. Below is the corrected code :

```
 public class LinkedList {

 private LinkedListNode head;

 public boolean find(Object data)
 {
      LinkedListNode temp = head;
      while(temp!= null)  // check if you have reached the tail
      {
           if(data.equals(temp.getData()))
           {
                return true;
           }
           temp = temp.getNext(); // move to the next node
      } // end of while loop
      return false;
  } // end of find method
}
```

Comment: That loop will run infinitely ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out...forgot to move to next node !!

Comment: Considering data and next are private... how exactly do I use this without making the attributes public?

Comment: Call correspondding getters...I have updated the answer

Comment: Yea I just realized I need to use get. Thanks!